# Why zombie process disappears from htop if i don't call waitpid()?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, zombie-process, waitpid, htop

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
                printf("I am Child\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        printf("I am Parent\n");
        while(1);
}
```

Here is what happens on my Linux when i run this code: zombie process shows up in htop for a  second and then just disappears.
I tried setting signal handler in parent:

```
void callback(int signum)
{
    return;
}

int main()
{
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
                printf("I am Child\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        printf("I am Parent\n");
        signal(SIGCHLD, callback);
        while(1);
}
```

But nothing changed. Why my zombie process disappears from htop?

P.S.: compiled with no optimization

**Update**: it doesn't show up in `htop` but does show up in `top`. Seems like a bug to me. I vote for deletion of this question.

Comment: Try running `ps | grep pts` and you'll probably see it.

Comment: @dbush nope, outputs nothing

Comment: `ps -u <your userid> --forest` should also make the zombie stand out.  I expect it's not _gone_ from htop's list, it's just all the way at the bottom (and probably hidden by the height of your terminal window) because it's not using any resources.

Comment: If you're in a different terminal from the process, run `ps aux | grep <name of binary>`, you should see two processes, one of which is defunct.

Comment: @zwol thanks that command works, the zombie show up as <defunct>. But it is actually _gone_ from htop.

Comment: The source for htop includes a "zombie" process status. So, it's probably either a filter feature or a bug. I found no issues that included the word zombie. You ought to add an issue there.

Answer (score 3):

The process disappears from `htop` because by default it sorts by CPU usage, so a zombie process will be so far down the list that it's off the screen.

It happens after one second because that's the default `htop` refresh interval.

Comment: It's not far down. I don't have many processes running. And it is not showing up even if i use filter by command name. Is is just not in the list.

Comment: Are you saying that you see multiple blank lines at the bottom when `htop` is running because it does not have enough processes to fill the screen?

Comment: Correct. And it doesn't show up in `htop` but shows up in `top` as i just tested it.

Comment: That's odd. It shows up in my `htop` when I sort by State reversed. What happens if you get the pid from `top` and run `htop -p thatpid`?

Comment: The result of `htop -p thatpid` is blank list of processes.

Comment: Did you replace `thatpid` when the number you got from `top`?

Comment: Yes, i did replace it :) I just used your notation to answer.

Comment: Huh. This is Linux proper, and not WSL or git bash or something, right?

Comment: It is WSL actually. `uname -a`: Linux DESKTOP-IOF2KQN 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #1151-Microsoft Thu Jul 22 21:05:00 PST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Your question is tagged `linux`. Can you try it on Linux and see if it still reproduces?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236110/discussion-between-vadim-novoshinskiy-and-that-other-guy).